# CollapsingToolbarLayout toolbar is in the status bar

Tags: android, android-layout, material-design, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I followed this tutorial on how to implement collapsing toolbar layout [Link Here](http://www.androidsources.com/index.php/2015/08/08/android-collapsing-toolbar-animation-using-design-support-library/)
And I successfully get the result what i want.
After some debugging I found my action bar search button is above the image which supposed to be inside the image.
What I'm doing is put the search icon inside the image just like any other collpsing toolbar layout.
And the image should occupy the top(colorPrimaryDark).

[image]

Here's my XML.(Based on the tutorial on the given link)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#FAFAFA">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="270dp"

        >

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="28dp"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/img_content"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:background="@drawable/gameover2"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax" />

            <include
                android:id="@+id/app_bar"
                layout="@layout/app_bar" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingTop="16dp">

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingBottom="24dp"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/coordinatar_card"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/coordinatar_card_desc"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="24dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/appBarLayout_card"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/appBarLayout_card_desc"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

            <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:paddingTop="24dp">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:text="@string/collapsing_toolbar_card"
                        android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Title"
                        android:textIsSelectable="false"
                        android:textSize="25sp" />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/collapsing_toolbar_card_desc"
                        android:textSize="18sp" />

                </LinearLayout>

            </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_search"
        app:layout_anchor="@+id/appbarLayout"
        app:layout_anchorGravity="bottom|right|end" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

And my Activity..

```
public class selectedPOI extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private JuanAdapter adapter;
    CollapsingToolbarLayout collapsingToolbar;
    int mutedColor = R.attr.colorPrimary;
    FloatingActionButton fab;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_selected_poi);
        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

        collapsingToolbar = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) findViewById(R.id.collapsing_toolbar);
        collapsingToolbar.setTitle("Collapsing Toolbar");
        fab=(FloatingActionButton)findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Snackbar.make(v, "You clicked on the fab", Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == android.R.id.home) {
            NavUtils.navigateUpFromSameTask(this);
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }


}
```

EDIT:
On API 21 or higher, The ActionBar is above the image.
But in API lower than API21, Its working fine.

Comment: show us your style for v21 if you have used

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base">
        <item name="android:windowTranslucentStatus">true</item>
        <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/primaryColorDark</item>
        <item name="android:colorControlHighlight">@color/colorHighlight</item>
    </style>
</resources>

tried to remove windowstranslucent, it fixed the problem but i want the picture to fit to top screen.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i think there can be two solution to this problem of yours. 
1. You can add this to your style  `<item name="android:fitsSystemWindows">true</item>` in v21 style. This will allow each screen of your app to adjust to only the area which is meant for your app.

2. Other way could be by code , try this

   toolbar.setPadding(0,getStatusBarHeight(this), 0, 0);
   here the toolbar is the your collapsing toolbar. Put this check for lollypop, if it is, then add top padding to your toolbar same as of height of status bar.

> ```
> public static int getStatusBarHeight(Context ctx) {
>         int result = 0;
>         int resourceId = ctx.getResources().getIdentifier("status_bar_height", "dimen","android");
>
>
>         if (resourceId > 0) {
>             result = ctx.getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(resourceId);
>         }
>         return result;
>     }
> ```

Let us know, how it went, i think it should do it for you.